# How to program a website search with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, search-engine

Ok so I am a total beginner when it comes to creating something like this. I am looking to integrate a search function into my website (Currently being built and in the early stages). The website will be a photography site and I would like to have a search function available which is very similar to this website found [Here](http://www.lik.com) As in I need it to return results of photos that are on my site and possibly blog entries, news items that will eventually exist.

I do not have the faintest idea where to start. I have done some research into search functionality, PHP database MYSQL etc and its confusing me.

Some things I would not like is having any ads on my site through using 3rd party search engines, and one of the main things im interested in on the above page is how it grabs the search results and displays them in a page layout of my choice.

Any help would be much appreciated in the form of where to start. I am a very keen learner so am open to any suggestions. Even if its just the steps I need to take and then I can research/learn accordingly

Many thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Look at tigzag or w3schools and take those tutorials.

Comment: Have you given any thought to using a CMS like Drupal, WordPress, Joomla, etc? Your site sounds like a primary candidate for CMS.

Comment: use CMS like wordpress or drupal.

Comment: Already started creating the site unfortunately and have put quite a bit of work in to warrent changing it to a CMS.

Comment: I don't think this question is completely vague. @franciru is trying to take some guidance, like which tool to use etc, to implement the search functionality across the site.

Comment: @j08691  Are you people blind??? I read rules and regulations. Im asking for specific recomendations on the steps needed to create a search function. Im not asking you to write a book for me. I want my question reopened.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="something.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

In your PHP script, you'd just do something similar to mysql %like%.  The % specifies a wildcard so that if the name of what you're searching for is "over" then it will return "stackoverflow".  Just be sure to escape your query.  After you do your query (which I won't write out because it will be different if you're using procedural vs. OOP vs. a framework) then you can do a while() loop to display all of your results

```
$qry = "select * from my_table where name like %".$this->real_escape_string($_POST['search'])." order by name";
```

If you give me some more info about your DB, your programming style, I can help you more.  I'd definitely check out some tutorials though as this is a VERY simple approach to search.